# mean of an arbitrary distribution

Tags: probability-distributions

Is it possible to find the mean or center of a continuous arbitrary distribution. Assuming that an object O is arbitrarily distributed within arbitrary shape, can we find its mean or center geometrically or by any other method if the distribution is not known in advance.

Comment: Can we find the center of some random thing we know nothing about? Err... I don't think continuity is enough here.

Comment: Can mean of an arbitrary object lies at the boundary of that object?

Comment: Some distributions don't have means.  For example, the Cauchy distribution whose density is $(1/\pi)/(1+x^2)$.

Comment: @shaikh: Yes. For example, the center of mass of a line segment lies on its boundary.